# How we can store address(this) in another address type variable?

Tags: solidity

```
contractAddress = address(this);

I am trying like this but giving error - TypeError: Type address is not implicitly convertible to expected type address payable
```

Here I want put address(this) in contractAddress , how is it possible.
I am on learning stage.

Comment: sorry I just want to allocate value of ADDRESS(THIS) in contractAddress .
like this , contractAddress  = ADDRESS(THIS), 
Is it possible in any way because above code is not working

Comment: The first answer has the solution for solc 0.6 and 0.5, which version are you using?